# Core Data modal entity objects creation getting unexpected results

Tags: ios, core-data

[image]
[image]

I am using CoreData for my Project.

1. In first image i selected `Site` to create the entity object.
2. After clicking the next. If you see the second image, `Game` files are created.

Here i want to create entity object for `Site`, But it is creating `Game` entity object. Please help me out.

Comment: What class name have you give `Site` in the right panel in the core data editor? (You can also see the name in the Default configuration in the core data editor)

Comment: i checked Default Configuration, for Entity 'Site' - Class 'Game' is there. Now i changed 'Game' to 'Site'. Now it is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've added an answer with some hand screen shots for completeness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the class name in the right hand panel is what you want it to be. You can also access this in the configuration editor for the Default configuration.

**Right side panel**
[image: Right side panel]

**Configuration**
[image: Configuration]